# Hold a comment in the queue if it contains [X] or more links

Tags: options, spam

I don't understand this option.

The English version of the description says:

> Hold a comment in the queue if it contains **[X] or more** links

The German version says:

> Einen Kommentar in die Warteschlange schieben, wenn er mehr als [X] Links enthält.
> [ Hold a comment in the queue if it contains **more than [X]** links. ]

I guess that the original English version can be considered more correct.

The English version means that if I choose "0", then all comments without any links should be published right away, and any comments with 1 or more links should get held in the comment queue. Right?

Why then does wpbeginner [recommend](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/vital-tips-and-tools-to-combat-comment-spam-in-wordpress/) that this should be set to "a number higher than zero", or else all comments will go into the comment queue? That recommendation is consistent with the German version of the description.

So, what does "[X] or more" mean here? Does it mean `number of links > x` or `number of links >= x` ?

Comment: I'm guessing if zero is chosen, then the option doesn't apply. But if you want to hold all comments with one or more link(s), then just chose one as your value.

Comment: @ialocin It seems that that is what my blog does.

Comment: So it is a issue of bad documentation and translation.